# Groovy catkin_create_pkg

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, catkin-create-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having the following message every time I try to use **catkin_create_pkg**. Any idea how to solve this???

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/catkin_create_pkg", line 71, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/catkin_create_pkg", line 64, in main
    newfiles={})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package_templates.py", line 211, in create_package_files
    newfiles[cmake_path] = create_cmakelists(package_template, rosdistro)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package_templates.py", line 275, in create_cmakelists
    return ctemp.substitute(temp_dict)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/string.py", line 121, in substitute
    return self.pattern.sub(convert, self.template)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/string.py", line 111, in convert
    val = mapping[named]
KeyError: 'include_folder_comment'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106961/groovy-catkin_create_pkg/) by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 649 on 2013-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it was a similar problem as the one described by tfoote, but instead of using pip, I was using the git repository. I deleted the catkin_ executable files and it works like charm right now (or it seems so)

---

Originally posted by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) with karma: 649 on 2013-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0